# Image set on UItableviewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have three images: Normal, highlighted, and selected. How do I set it in a `Tableview` custom cell?

I've tried this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (selected) {
        self.highlighted = NO;
        self.imgBackgroundCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[MTUtility setImageWithName:@"listselected"]];
    }

} 
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animate {
    if (highlighted) {
        self.imgBackgroundCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[MTUtility setImageWithName:@"listpressed"]];
    }
}
```

But highlighted remains as it is many times.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your code:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (selected) {
        self.highlighted = NO;
        self.imgBackgroundCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[MTUtility setImageWithName:@"listselected"]];
    }
    else{
       ...unselect code
    }

} 
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animate {
    if (highlighted) {
        self.imgBackgroundCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[MTUtility setImageWithName:@"listpressed"]];
    }
    else{
      ...unhighlight
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selected image on `didselectrowatindexpath`, then you can set UITableviewCell's property setSelectedBackgroundView in cellForRowAtIndexPath method as follows:

```
    - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
{
....
UIImageView *normalCellBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

[normalCellBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_nonselected.png"]];//Set Image for Normal
[normalCellBG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setBackgroundView:normalCellBG];


UIImageView *selecetedCellBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
[selecetedCellBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_selected.png"]];//Set Name for selected Cell
[selecetedCellBG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selecetedCellBG ];

}
```

Let me know if this is what you need to do.